# Which systems are available for reducing risk by swapping/pooling income, sometimes called "equity exchange"

Tags: profit-share

I have always thought that startups should swap some equity with other startups in order to lower the extreme risk they take on, similarly to what venture capital companies do by having portfolios.

Freelancers could also hedge risk by doing something similar.

If this is combined with, say an incubator or some social setting where freelancers help each other, risk hedging and helping your fellow freelancer would not only be nice, but profitable.

I have been looking for solutions in this space, and I have only found one, The Founders Club which is for startups where there is an equity exchange in a pool of other startups managed by VCs.

What I am asking for is other examples of equity exchange, rating systems connected to risk hedging or similar systems where risk hedging is done for startups or freelancers.

Comment: Hello user and welcome to Freelancing SE. Our site works best for questions about real, actual problems you're facing as a freelancer. Questions that only serve to build lists of things are tough to vet with voting, as it's tough to tell what the best answers are. Please see [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more details. Good luck!